# SumoLogic dashboards - how do I automate?

Tags: infrastructure-as-code, sumologic

I am getting some experience with SumoLogic dashboards and alerting. I would like to have all possible configuration in code. Does anyone have experience with automation of SumoLogic configuration? At the moment I am using Ansible for general server and infra provisioning.

Thanks for all info!

Best Regards,
Rafal.

Answer (score 0):

(The dashboards, alerts, etc. are referred to as Content in Sumo Logic parlance)

You can use the [Content Management API](https://api.sumologic.com/docs/#tag/contentManagement), especially the [content-import-job](https://api.sumologic.com/docs/#operation/beginAsyncImport). I am not an expert in Ansible, but I am not aware of any way to plug that API into Ansible.

Also there's a community Terraform provider for Sumo Logic and [it supports content](https://github.com/SumoLogic/terraform-provider-sumologic/blob/master/website/docs/r/content.html.markdown):

```
resource "sumologic_content" "test" {
parent_id = "%s"
  config = 
    {
        "type": "SavedSearchWithScheduleSyncDefinition",
        "name": "test-333",
        "search": {
            "queryText": "\"warn\"",
            "defaultTimeRange": "-15m",
[...]
```

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic

Comment: Thanks, Grzegorz, for provided info. Are you able to tell if Content Management API may be usable for dashboard and metric monitor's creation?

Comment: Yes, both of them. I only remember the former being called `DashboardSyncDefinition`. The latter is most likely `MetricsSavedSearchSyncDefinition` (I only see the public doc right now).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the shell script to import the dashboard. Here it is SumoLogic AU instance. eg: https://api.au.sumologic.com/api. This will be changed based on your country.

Note: You can export all of your dashboard as json files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# if you are using AWS parameter store
# accessKey=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name path_to_your_key --with-decryption  --query 'Parameter.Value' --region=ap-southeast-2 |  tr -d \")
# accessSecret=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name name path_to_your_secret  --with-decryption --query 'Parameter.Value' --region=ap-southeast-2 |  tr -d \")
# yourDashboardFolderName="xxxxx" # this is the folder id in the sumologic where you want to create dashboards

# if you are using just key and secreat
accessKey= "your_sumologic_key"
accessSecret= "your_sumologic_secret"
yourDashboardFolderName="xxxxx" # this is the folder id in the sumologic


# you can place all the json files of dashboard in ./Sumologic/Dashboards folder.
for f in $(find ./Sumologic/Dashboards -name '*.json'); \
do \
curl -X POST https://api.au.sumologic.com/api/v2/content/folders/$yourDashboardFolderName/import \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u "$accessKey:$accessSecret" \
-d @$f \
;done
```